# Screen frozen after power saving mode

Tags: 14.04, freeze

My problem is the following:

The computer seems completely frozen after power saving mode. I cannot move the mouse and it seems that the no combination of keys do anything. The only thing I can do is a hard reboot by shutting down the computer!
I have this problem since I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04.

Anybody has an idea how I can fix this issue?

My computer:

- Intel® Core™ i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4
- AMD Radeon HD 7400M Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the driver, if it still doesn't work, you can try to disable the dedicated graphic card via the Catalyst Control Center (`amdcccle` or `amdcccle-updates`, depending on the driver).

In this way you will only use the Intel card integrated in the i3 CPU.

This has a couple of side effects.

1. almost surely suspension (and maybe even hybernation) will work
2. you will consume a lot less power when on battery (the AMD card will be switched off)
3. if you need more graphic power you can always reactivate your card via the Catalyst Control Center and reboot (with Nvidia you just need a logout-login, maybe that is enough also for AMD)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I still had trouble after the update, but disable the dedicated graphic card solved my problem.